# VMWare Virtual Network Editor - Bridged Network not working since switch

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, switch

I want to connect my virtual Debain server to the LAN via a **bridged network**. The virtual bridged network is configured in the VMWare **Virtual Network Editor** (**VmNet0** - Bridged), the right NIC has been selected by me - so its not set to auto-bridging.

My problem now is, that this setup worked for me until a **switch was plugged between** my workstation (that is running the VM) and the router. (It used to work with the setting Custom - Specific virtual network: VMNet 0 - selected in the virtual machine settings)

What changed need to be done to get this or a similar configuration working - with the switch.

So my goal is to give the virtual server its own IP - so that I can **access it from any of my local PCs**...

Thanks in advance for all tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that the firewall of my host computer somehow "magically" changed its configuration - after a certain number of ingoing connections I guess.

At the same time I started using the switch. So these two events collided by accident...

Sorry for your time!